# How to bind ./gradlew with android app performance for debugging

Tags: android, linux, debugging, console, gradlew

usually I'm using Linux command "./gradlew installDebug" for building and installing my app on real device. But it isn't allow me keep stacktrace and observe my app processing for Exceptions and Errors.
Can you help me bind app processing with my Linux console for debugging?